# How to auto get Module A when install Module B in magento2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, module, composer

For example I have two modules, **Demo** and **Base**. I want that when Module **Demo** gets installed, module **Base** is automatically fetched from Github and installed.

I think it is related to composer.

**Edited**
i trying to put code file composer.json of **module A**

```
{
    "name": "namespace/modulea",
    "description": "N/a",
    "require": {
        "php": "~5.6.0|7.0.2|~7.0.6",
        "magento/module-store": "100.1.*",
        "magento/module-backend": "100.1.*",
        "magento/framework": "100.1.*",
        "namespace/moduleb": "101.0.1"
    },
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "101.1.3",
    "license": [
        "OSL-3.0",
        "AFL-3.0"
    ],
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ],
        "psr-4": {
            "Namspace\\ModuleA\\": ""
        }
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/xxx/moduleb.git"
        }
    ]
}
```

it true?

Answer (score 4):

The composer.json of module B should contain:

```
"require": {
    "module/a": "*"
}
```

Where `module/a` is the `name` as defined in the composer.json of module A.

`*` means "any version", but you should replace that with a version dependency, like `1.0.0` for exactly 1.0.0 or `~1.2.3` for anything from 1.2.3 but below 1.3.0

Versions should be Git tags.

Read more: https://getcomposer.org/doc/

---

One more thing to consider: if module A is not on the Magento marketplace, but only on Github, the project where module B is installed needs to define the repository in its composer.json:

```
"repositories": [
    {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://github.com/module/a.git"
    }
]
```

But you can publish module A to [packagist](https://packagist.org/), the default composer package repository to avoid that step.

Comment: Thanks @fabianschmengler I edited my question. How to when i run cli: `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` it auto get ModuleB in github and install this.

Comment: Not possible with bin/magento, you need to run composer install first. And it only works if you install the first module with composer as well

Comment: Note that the marketplace installer uses composer internally, so if module B is installed from marketplace, module a will be installed from github as well

Comment: "thanks" @fabianschmengler.I had build a module **Base** it's module parent for some my module future and i want when user installing module child then auto get module ***Base***. Any suggestion?

Comment: I already answered it. If this is not working for you, you should update your question with details about how users install your module or why a composer based solution is not working for you (or what you do not understand about it)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51274/discussion-between-xanka-and-fabian-schmengler).